# fontspec does not work correctly. MiKTeX portable, no admin rights

Tags: fonts, xetex, installing, miktex, fontspec

I am trying to set up a TeX System at work, where I have no admin rights. So I went for MiKTeX portable. It is "installed" on my Desktop. I want to use `fontspec` with XeLaTeX to be able to choose the fonts I want.

I can compile a normal document, but when I try to use `fontspec`, XeLaTeX throws an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \c_keys_code_root_tl 
                            fontspec/Ligatures/Historical
l.8 ...tureoption{Ligatures}{Historic}{Historical}
```

which can be ignored by pressing enter. But then there is the critical error:

```
(c:\Users\**********\Desktop\Miktex\tex\latex\metalogo\metalogo.sty))Running miktex-makemf.exe...
miktex-makemf: The Charis SIL source file could not be found.

Running hbf2gf.exe...


hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.0)



Couldn't find `Charis S.cfg'

miktex-maketfm: No creation rule for font "Charis SIL".


!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Charis SIL" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.10 \setmainfont{Charis SIL}
                          % set the main body font (\textrm), assumes Ch...
```

I've tried several fonts, none of them worked. Googling for the error message did not help either. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Nearly forgot to post the document:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8

\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\setmainfont{Charis SIL} % set the main body font (\textrm), assumes Charis SIL is installed


\begin{document}
Hello World

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post. Also, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What fonts did you try? If you really don't have admin rights, it should be impossible for you to install new fonts (as that requires admin rights I believe). Your example runs fine if I use a font that is preinstalled (tried with Times New Roman).

Comment: Your fontspec version is outdated. `\c_keys_code_root_tl` has been removed from the l3-code and also from the fontspec code. The rest of your code should work if xetex can find the font. But perhaps you will have to update the font cache first with the command `fc-cache`.

Comment: The documentation of `fontspec` tells you how to use fonts that aren't installed as system fonts. Check section 4 of the documentation, particularly subsection 4.2.

Comment: @mythio: I tried Charis SIL, Times New Roman, Arial.

Comment: Pete, make an update of your portable MiKTeX installation and then try again (see Ulrike’s comment).

Answer (score 5):

Your fontspec version is outdated. `\c_keys_code_root_tl` has been removed from the l3-code and also from the fontspec code. The rest of your code should work if xetex can find the font. But perhaps you will have to update the font cache first with the command `fc-cache`.